# Force character inclusion in string displaying

Tags: swift, string, format, number-formatting

I am manually displaying a string printing a USD price as follows:

```
let price : String = String(format:"%.2f", finalPrice)
priceLabel.text = String("$" + price)
```

Is there any way to add the `,` every 3 digit without using `NumberFormatter`? I couldn't find the corresponding `format` code for that if any.

Comment: Why not use NumberFormatter? It has a "currency" style and a "groupingSeparator" property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to USE the NumberFormatter.

Your code would look like this:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.groupingSeparator = ","
priceLabel.text = formatter.string(for: price)
```

Comment: it is  `"en_US"` not `"us_US"`, no need to set the `maximumFractionDigits` when using `.currency` style and you can use `Formatter`
 method `string(for: Any)` instead of initializing a new `NSNumber`

Comment: Better approach would be setting the currency symbol and let the Locale (`.current`) / User Settings define the groupingSeparator. You shouldn't define how the user will display currency

Comment: Yeah, but in this case he wants to use $ as currency. And thanks for the editing I kind of copied a part of my code and didn't checked it that close.

Comment: As I said you can set only the currency symbol. No need to change the `Locale`. You might need to set the `minimumFractionDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits`  to 2 considering that in Chile it would be zero

Comment: Ah, yes that would be a better approach

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you! For now I am trying to force the display to `USD` with 2 digits and King's answer does the trick perfectly. I thought I could do it with fewer lines by not using `NumberFormatter` but this method seems to be more convenient.